# LINQ: dot notation equivalent for JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, syntax, linq-query-syntax

Consider this LINQ expression written using query notation:

```
 List<Person> pr = (from p in db.Persons
                     join e in db.PersonExceptions
                     on p.ID equals e.PersonID
                     where e.CreatedOn >= fromDate
                     orderby e.CreatedOn descending
                     select p)
                   .ToList();
```

**Question:** how would you write this LINQ expression using dot notation?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<Person> pr = db.Persons
                    .Join(db.PersonExceptions,
                          p => p.ID,
                          e => e.PersonID,
                          (p, e) => new { p, e })
                    .Where(z => z.e.CreatedOn >= fromDate)
                    .OrderByDescending(z => z.e.CreatedOn)
                    .Select(z => z.p)
                    .ToList();
```

Note how a new anonymous type is introduced to carry both the `p` and `e` bits forward. In the specification, query operators which do this use *transparent identifiers* to indicate the behaviour.

Comment: And when Jon Skeet isn't immediately available, you can use Resharper to get the same answer.

Comment: For details of when that would be, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep/566#566 - oh, and C# in Depth goes into all of this as well, of course. It's like having a miniature version of me on your bookshelf ;)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Reading your book just this week. Thanks very much! I'll likely stick to query notation in cases like these.

Comment: I'd like to see the dot notation for two joins (i.e. three sources).  I'm not talking about multiple join conditions, I'm talking about multiple joins.  A long google hunt has turned up no examples.